# unable to find my hard drives in ubuntu 14.04 in device

Tags: windows, nautilus, hard-drive, data-recovery, data-loss

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in my old pc by erasing Windows 7. When I opened my files in Ubuntu, I didn't find my hard drives under *Device*. The only one option available was *Computer*.

Is there anyway that I could get my data and hard drives back?

Comment: remember, your partitions will not longer be called c: d: or e: like they used to in windows.

Comment: See let me tell you the whole scene...

Comment: See let me tell you the whole scene...when chose the try ubuntu in the installation menu of ubuntu after that i clicked on install ubuntu. A window appears asking do you want to boot alongside windows, only ubuntu(it will erase all your data) or other options. I clicked on boot only ubuntu( without knowing that this will erase all my data in hard drives and also ot is my first time). I wasnt either connected to internet. Whwn i opend files it only showd computer under devices. Please tell me is there any way that i can get my data and hard drives back?

Comment: And there I would have though that “will erase all your data” would scare people enough about possibly erasing all their data…

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not quite sure sure what you exactly mean by "opening your files" and where you were expecting your hard drives to appear, I'll take a stab at it.

My guess is that you haven't lost your data.  My guess is that you just don't have the disk mounted.

If indeed you have multiple hard drives, other than the one you're running ubuntu on, Ubuntu doesn't automatically mount them; you need to manually do that.

**Here's how**

To keep it simple, let's do this via the terminal so go ahead and open that.

then enter the following to list all available disks and their respective partitons on the system.

```
lsblk
```

My output looks like this:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  29.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   833M  0 part /boot
└─sda2   8:2    0  25.2G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   667M  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdb5   8:21   0  11.2G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sdb6   8:22   0  18.6G  0 part 
├─sdb7   8:23   0 344.6G  0 part /home
└─sdb8   8:24   0  90.7G  0 part 
sdc      8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0 931.5G  0 part
```

As noted in the comments, you won't see C: or D: or whatever.  Instead you'll see something like `sda` (for example) and then its respective partitions `sda1` and `sda2`.  `Sda` is an actual disk which is divided into partitions 1 and 2.

The best way to tell what it is is by the size of each disk and its description, product and vendor.  I know, for example that my solid state drive is `/dev/sda` above because it's 30Gigs.  I then can guess what each partition does based on its size, mountpoint etc.  Worst case scenario I can try mounting each one and seeing what I find.

Now you are ready to mount the partition.  So if we wanted to mount `/dev/sda1` we would run

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Then to check out the files, you just navigate to the directory /mnt and browse it like a regular directory (as that's pretty much what it is).

To unmount the partition (like if you wanted to use mnt to check another partition) run the following:

```
sudo umount /mnt
```

If you want to mount it each time you run the machine, there are a variety of gui mount managers out there that can help you.

Comment: NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT

sda 8:0 0 149.1G 0 disk

├─sda1 8:1 0 147.6G 0 part /

├─sda2 8:2 0 1K 0 part

└─sda5 8:5 0 1.5G 0 part [SWAP]

sajal@sajal-945GCMX-S2:~$

Comment: This is what i see right now.

Comment: @SajalAroraSazz Ah, I just read your comment above describing the whole situation.  It's doubtful that your windows system will work after recovering your partitions but you should be able to get your documents back with this: http://askubuntu.com/a/286206/193869